# Display alerts are not enabling in excel file from access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm writing contents of tables from access to excel(Opening the excel file from access) After writing it i'm trying to save all workbooks in the *appXL* application. For that i'm making *DispalyAlerts* false before saving and trun on back after saving. After writing contents to excel i'm closing the access. After writing ,when i'm trying to close the excel, it is not giving any alerts like Do you want to save the contents?

My vba code

```
       Sub Writexl()

       Dim appXL As Excel.Application
       Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
       StrwbPath="C:\temp\sample.xls"

       Set appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
       With appXL
       Set wb = .Workbooks.Open(StrwbPath)
       .Visible = True

       End With

       'here code for writing contents          


        'save workbook after writing

        appXL.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

       For Each w In appXL.Application.Workbooks
       w.Save
       Next w

        appXL.Application.DisplayAlerts = True

       DoCmd.Quit acQuitSaveAll
       Application.Quit
       End sub
```

Comment: Where are you closing Excel? I see an `Application.Quit` but that is not the Excel.Application.  Also, I believe if ALL open workbooks  are saved, then there is no alert to display.

Comment: I'm not closing excel, it still opens after writing as per requirement. Is there any way we can enable display alerts after saving the contents or writing the contents.

Comment: Alerts *are* enabled, unless you're doing something else to turn them off. As currently described, there simply are no alerts to display when you close Excel. All the workbooks are saved. There is nothing to alert you about.

Comment: Did you at some point stop your code before it finished running? Or perhaps it erred after setting `DisplayAlerts = False`?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `DisplayAlerts` to the Application's Applicaiton

```
appXL.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

is conceptually equivalent to

```
Excel.Application.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

So the property is being set on the parent application to Excel.

Try

```
appXL.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: hmmm but he also did that assignment when setting it to `False`, so in practice that didn't actually set the `Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False` to begin with. So this change, while a good recommendation, I don't think it is the solution.

Comment: @DavidZemens True. You're absolutely right. `AppXL.Application` is self referencing. I thought it might be giving a reference to Access ... nope. In fact I tried the OP's code and it seems to work. I think you're comment is correct. Everything is saved, there is nothing to alert.

Comment: @Brad Thanks for the reply. tried before but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

> After writing ,when i'm trying to close the excel, it is not giving
>   any alerts like Do you want to save the contents?

As @David Zemens says, why would it display a message to save all changes when you've already saved everything. Have you tried changing a cell and then exiting Excel?